# Adding specific colors to the rows of the table based on the different hero superpowers

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to ensure that the rows of the table have colors based on the Hero Superpower. For example if the hero has super strength, its row color will be color: red, if FLying row color will be color: blue

I cant bind the data together and create the row colors based on the hero superpower.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Hero ID</th>
    <th>Hero Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Superpower</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
      <td><span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="badge">{{hero.gender}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="badge">{{hero.age}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="badge">{{hero.superpowers}}</span></td>
    </a>
    <td><button class="delete" title="delete hero" (click)="delete(hero)">X</button></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: please share the heroes object keys

Comment: Is superpowers an array?

Comment: see example answer:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-bddw1t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to change color based on **conditions** you can use the `ngStyle` directive like below.

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(hero.superpowers)}" >
              <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.gender}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.age}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="badge">{{hero.superpowers}}</span></td>
  </a>
    <td><button class="delete" title="delete hero"
        (click)="delete(hero)">X</button></td>

      </tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
  getColor(superpower) {
    console.log(superpower);
    switch (superpower) {
      case 'strength':
        return 'red';
      case 'FLying':
        return 'blue';
    }
  }
```

**[Here is a demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-oowk9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngStyle as shown below

```
<tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': hero.superpowers == 'flying'? 'blue': 'red' }">
```

Comment: I just come to post my example and see your answer:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-bddw1t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have other superpowers as well like 8 of them, so whenever the user changes the hero superpowers it will follow that specific color. so 8 heroes has 8 different row colors